# Python argparse for infinite number of inputs and flag requiring multiple arguments?

Tags: python, argparse, software-design

I have a Python library which users currently run via

```
python main.py
```

`main.py` will call other `*.py` scripts within the same directory, and the program runs to completion.

My problem is, users of this software should be able to input (in theory) an infinite number of "events", whereby users need to specific 4 pieces of information: "category" (string), "type" (string), "start_time" (integer), and "end_time" (integer). By default, if nothing is no flag is used, no "events" are schedule, and the program runs by default. Users must give each of the 4 arguments at once for each "event", or otherwise there's an error message. Users should be able to schedule as many "events" as need be.

At the moment, I'm not sure of the best way to allow users to pass in argument variables using `argparse`, whereby (1) they can pass in dozens of arguments at once and (2) 4 categories are required. Is this possible? What is the data structure used, a dicitionary via argparse?

For only one such input, the naïve approach could be to use argparse, and force users to use the following format

python main.py ---user_specify "category1", 1233, 1452, 1673

whereby in the `main.py` script I have something like

```
 import argparse
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 parser.add_argument("user_specify", action="store_true", default=False)
```

That's quite clumsy. The bigger problem is that it doesn't solve the issue of allowing users to pass through dozens of such arguments.

What is the correct pythonic way to do this?

Is it possible to pass through dictionaries? How does one would with multiple inputs using the same argparse flag though?

Comment: I would define argument with a '--event' flag and `nargs=4`, and `action='append'`.  That will give you a nested list.  Parse the sublists into strings and integers as needed.

Comment: Do you have an example of how this would work? Also, I think this solves the problem if there's only 1 "event". What if a user want to include 100s of events? That's 400 variables after one flag, right? 
Maybe a JSON or dictionary would work better? I'm not sure what's the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: parser.add_argument('-e','--event',action='append',nargs=4)

In [5]: args = parser.parse_args('--event cetegory1 123 2 4 -e cat2 23 4 343'.split())
In [6]: args
Out[6]: Namespace(event=[['cetegory1', '123', '2', '4'], ['cat2', '23', '4', '343']])
```

Each `--event` flag marks a new list of 4 items.  Post parsing code could iterate through the sublists of `args.event` and convert the last 2 elements to integers.

Strings could also contain spaces if quoted.

For many such 'events' you could put them in a `@file` as described in

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars

If using the idea in https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.convert_arg_line_to_args

the file could look like

```
--event cetegory1 123 2 4 
-e "cat 2" 23 4 343
--event foo bar 4 2
...
```

Data like that could also be read as a `csv` file.  Parsing a `json` string is also an option.  An `argparse` argument with a `type=json.loads` parameter can read such a string from the input or an `@file`.

```
In [7]: import json
In [8]: parser.add_argument('-j',type=json.loads)
In [9]: argv = ['-j', '[["category1","123",3,4]]']
In [10]: parser.parse_args(argv)
Out[10]: Namespace(event=None, j=[['category1', '123', 3, 4]])
```

Comment: "Data like that could also be read as a csv file"

This is a pretty good idea. Users could pass a *csv with 4 columns. Any examples where this has been done previously?

Comment: There are lots of SO questions about reading data from `csv` files with `numpy` (arrays) or `pandas` (dataframes).  There's also a `csv` module.  But it's also easy to read and parse such a file directly, especially if you aren't doing anything fancy.

Comment: Ah, I think I've now put 2 and 2 together. It should be simple to read in the *csv file from the argument, of course. 
Thanks for the help!